# Moodle: Error in extracting downloaded zip submission

Tags: moodle, unzip

**From The Course page when I click download all submission zip file is downloaded. But I am not able to extract zip file as it gives following error.**

*Archive:  CS_632-2013-2-Project_final_submission-27762.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of CS_632-2013-2-Project_final_submission-27762.zip or
        CS_632-2013-2-Project_final_submission-27762.zip.zip, and cannot find CS_632-2013-2-Project_final_submission-27762.zip.ZIP, period.*

**This error is coming for all course submission downloads.**

Comment: This question should be directed to the administrators of the web application in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are right clicking the link and saving? This won't work, you need to actually click the link which will then automatically download the correct file.